# Validating the calendar date and poping an error dialog box

Tags: java

I am picking a date from the calendar through xhtml page .I need to validate the date .If the date is empty or the date is of past date ,it should pop up a dialog box indicating an error and then return to the same page for the input .

How do I check the date if it is the past date .I can validate the date using

```
Date date =new Date() ;
SimpleDateFormat ft =new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
if(datefromdatepicker ==null ||datefromdatepicker <ft.format(date)){
//How do I pop up a error dialog box ??
}
else {
//further operations
}
```

Are there any other better ways to do this .And how do I pop up dialog msg ?

Comment: Haves you tried using [compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-)?

Comment: Will then have to handle nullpointer exception also ..Is the code not lengthy

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2014-12-31");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("2015-10-31");

    if(date1 == null || date2 == null)
    //do you want

    else if(date1.after(date2))
        System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");

    else if(date1.before(date2))
        System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");

    else if(date1.equals(date2))
        System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
```

[Date before and after doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29)

Comment: Will then have to handle nullpointer exception also ..Is the code not lengthy